# Get first instance of SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

I have one table wherein we have set appointment entries, One user may have multiple appointments for same-day or different days. This can be inserted into the table.
Here my question is that for a new user when the first time we insert an appointment (one/many) systems should list at user name.

So may in one time in life for a user we got output that this user appointment is inserted.
After first time maybe next time we will not require this information, because we want to send email on generation of very first appointment of user.

I have the below query but if I run daily this got daily that new user entries.

```
create table #temp
(
userid int,
name1 varchar(20),
appointmentdate datetime,
addedon datetime
)

insert into #temp values(1,'john smith','2021/01/07',getdate())
insert into #temp values(1,'john smith','2021/02/07',getdate())

insert into #temp values(1,'Deuo Jha','2021/02/01',getdate())


select t1.userid,min(t1.appointmentdate) from #temp as t1 inner join 
#temp as t2 on 
t1.userid=t2.userid
group by t1.userid
```

Can you please help me to sort this out?

I want to have
when I run query at any time,it should return name whose entry done first time,today or yesterday

Comment: What is your expected output from this sample data?

Comment: when I run query at any time,it should return name whose entry done first time,today or yesterday

Comment: If appointments are for a specific date, then don't use DATETIME as the datatype. Do NOT encourage sloppy data recording or querying. Prevent it! And explain why you self-join your table? There does not appear to be any need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need simply this -

```
SELECT t1.userid, t1.name1, min(addedon)
  FROM #temp
 GROUP BY t1.userid, t1.name1
```

Comment: it does not consider, whether user was created only today or yesterday

Answer (score 0):

You can first findout the earliest addedOn date for each user. Later, apply filter to see if the user was created since yesterday.

```sql
create table #temp
(
userid int,
name1 varchar(20),
appointmentdate datetime,
addedon datetime
)

insert into #temp values(1,'john smith','2021/01/07','2021/01/07')
insert into #temp values(1,'john smith','2021/02/07',getdate())
insert into #temp values(2,'Deuo Jha','2021/02/01',getdate())

;with cte_userMinDate AS
(
SELECT userid, min(addedOn) as FirstCreatedDate FROM #temp
group by userid
)
SELECT userid 
from cte_userMinDate
where FirstCreatedDate > cast(dateadd(dd,-1,getdate()) as date) -- first created date > yesterday
```

| UserId |
| --- |
| 2 |